# Alternate Syntax fo assigning json data objectForKey to attributes of class

Tags: objective-c

Can i write last three lines of code in a single line:

```
NSArray* latestLoans = [self.JsonData objectForKey:@"loans"];
for (id object in latestLoans) {
NSDictionary* loan = object;
newModelClass.name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
newModelClass.sector = [loan objectForKey:@"sector"];
newModelClass.activity = [loan objectForKey:@"activity"];
```

my complete code is here and if there is any other best practice, please suggest me.

```
-(void)CopyOnlineData:(NSDictionary*)OnlineData{
 self.JsonData = OnlineData;
 NSArray* latestLoans = [self.JsonData objectForKey:@"loans"];
 for (id object in latestLoans) {
 NewModelClass *newModelClass = [[NewModelClass alloc] init];
 NSDictionary* loan = object;
 newModelClass.name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
 newModelClass.sector = [loan objectForKey:@"sector"];
 newModelClass.activity = [loan objectForKey:@"activity"];
 NSDictionary *loactionDictionary = loan[@"location"];
 newModelClass.country = loactionDictionary[@"country_code"];
 newModelClass.town = loactionDictionary[@"town"];
 NSDictionary *imageid = loan[@"image"];
 newModelClass.ImageId = imageid[@"id"];
 NSLog(@"name: %@ \n town: %@\n sector: %@\n country: %@\n activity: %@\n image id: %@", newModelClass.name,newModelClass.town,newModelClass.sector,newModelClass.country,newModelClass.activity,newModelClass.ImageId);
[self.tableData addObject:newModelClass];
}
[[self KivaTableView]reloadData];
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: No.  Why would you want to? Is your `Return` key breaking?

Comment: Not really, but you could handle the `loan` deserialization by creating a initializer that take the JSON dict: `NewModelClass *newModelClass = [[NewModelCalss alloc] initWithJSONDict:object]; [self.tableData addObject:newModelClass];` That way, if you have elsewhere a `NewModelClass` object to create from a dictionary, you have it ready.

Comment: Note that `for (id object in latestLoans){ NSDictionary *load = object;}` could be coded this way: `for (NSDictionary *loan in latestLoans){}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I would do:
 create a custom init for `NewModelClass` in order to remove it from this part of code. That way, if you have to create a new object of `NewModelClass`, you won't have to rewrite all the lines.

In *NewModelClass.h*:

```
-(id)initWithJSONDict:(NSDictionary *)dict;
```

In *NewModelClass.m*:

```
-(id)initWithJSONDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        self.sector = [dict objectForKey:@"sector"];
        self.activity = [dict objectForKey:@"activity"];
        NSDictionary *loactionDictionary = dict[@"location"];
        self.country = loactionDictionary[@"country_code"]; //or dict[@"location][@"country_code"];
        self.town = loactionDictionary[@"town"];//or dict[@"location][@"town"];
        NSDictionary *imageid = dict[@"image"];
        self.ImageId = imageid[@"id"];//or dict[@"image][@"id"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I'd override `description` too:

```
-(NSString *)description
{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ %p>: name: %@ \n town: %@\n sector: %@\n country: %@\n activity: %@\n image id:", [self class], self, self.name, self.town, self.sector, self.country, self.activity, self.ImageId ];
}
```

Then in your code:

```
-(void)addOnlineData:(NSDictionary*)onlineData
{
     self.JsonData = onlineData;
     NSArray* latestLoans = [self.JsonData objectForKey:@"loans"];
     for (NSDictionary *aLoan in latestLoans) 
     {
         NewModelClass *newModelClass = [[NewModelClass alloc] initWithJSONDict:aLoan];
         NSLog(@"Loan: %@", loan);
        [self.tableData addObject:newModelClass];
    }
    [[self KivaTableView]reloadData];
}
```

Modification of the for loop, since you already know it's a `NSDictionary`, so no use of `for id`, then `id` cast to `NSDictionary`.

Modification of the method name:
Start method with a lower case.
Avoid naming starting with "copy" if you don't do a copy.

Note: This code is not tested, it may not compile due to a light syntax error, but you should get the main idea.