# I could not get the values from NSDictionary in Model class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

In my iPhone App.

**Problem: When I am trying to get the value from dictionary in model class it is giving me the nil values.**

**Why this is happening, is this the memory management issue ?**

I did this,

**I am passing NSDictionary, from my viewController to NSMutableArray Category and from that I am passing it to my Modelclass.**

If you want to see the coding,

1. In my ViewController.m file

   [arrayNews convertToNewsArticles];
2. In my NSMutableArray category I am calling method convertToNewsArticles.

   for(NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in self) {

   ```
         NewsArticle *newsArticle=[[NewsArticle alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
           [arrayConverted addObject:newsArticle];

       }
   ```

**I am talking about this dictionary that I am passing.**

3. Here is my Model class

   -(NewsArticle*)initWithDictionary:dictionary{

   ```
   self.title=dictionary[@"title"];

   self.author=dictionary[@"author"];


   self.urlString=dictionary[@"url"];


   return self;
   ```

   }

Update:

I solved by using IAModelBase class on GitHub.[IAModelBase](https://github.com/oarrabi/IAModelBase)

Comment: where is your custom object?

Comment: Why have you subclassed NSMutableArray?  You are changing the semantics of `initWithArray`.  This code belongs somewhere else; probably in the object that is fetching the news articles, but if you insist on doing this you just need to say `[self addObject:newsArticle]`  Have you read the **Subclassing notes** in the NSMutableArray class reference?

Comment: I support @Paulw11. Your code design is completly wrong. Also this question has classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), so please describe what are you trying to achieve not how you try to do it!

Comment: Custom objects, I made one class, added properties, and added initWithDictionary method ?

Comment: @Paulw11, Marek R, yes I have a doubts about that. So, I hesitate to do. I would asked before that How to design custom objects model classes. Wait for my update. please.

Comment: Here is an example I gave on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409944/alternate-syntax-fo-assigning-json-data-objectforkey-to-attributes-of-class/37410905#37410905

Comment: @Paulw11 I have used NSMutableArray Category, and added one more method.

Comment: @Larme I hae done the samething but I could not get the dictionary working in my model class. I think memory's retain count is not getting foraword.

Comment: @Larme the thing is that I have added the for loop that you have mentioned  is I have taken in the NSMutable category.

Answer (score 1):

If it is subclass of `NSMutableArray` then you can add object like,

```
  [self addObject:newsArticle];
```

in your for loop and `return self` will return your final mutable array and you can use it as per desired need!

And refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/) for more detail. You have to implement some mandatory methods if you want to `subclass` the `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: the problem is I could not pass the NSDictionary to my model class. When I am trying to get the value from dictionary in model clas it is giving me the nil value. See my updated question, otherwise I have done the same thing that you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to convert NSDictionary Objects to Model Objects.
I could not pass the whole dictionary to Model class. Like mentioned in the question.

But instead I used,
[IAModel classes](https://github.com/oarrabi/IAModelBase)

Read the readme file. 
Also see the 1st Issue,it is solved. 
[Pull Issue](https://github.com/oarrabi/IAModelBase/pulls)